# Web Part Page Issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, classic-experience

I am currently displaying a SharePoint List in a Web Part page, and have selected the "Display Search Box" miscellaneous option.

I want to utilize the Summary View as it stretches the columns out more to take up a greater width on the page (thus less white space).

When I alter the view then edit the view, the Search Box disappears. What causes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my testing,  in List/App web part does not support to display search box.

If you want to enable search box in list web part, you have to use the Standard list view.

Comment: What is the Difference between the Summary and Default view? When you edit the web part it still shows as default style which should allow the Display Search box functionality still

Comment: Summary view has different styling than standard view, at least for me it is different.